# Move icon down on hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an icon on my page and I'd like to animate it's position down the page a little with jQuery. This will happen on hover. Move it down 40px.

When I am off hover, it will move slowly back to where it was.

`<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5uamyea1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just with CSS?

https://jsfiddle.net/5uamyea1/

```
.fa{position:relative;transition:top 0.5s;top:0}
.fa:hover{top:20px}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '.fa-chevron-circle-down' ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'hover' );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( 'hover' );
  }
);
```

and you could do the animation in css. Otherwise replace those lines with jquery animate

Answer (score 0):

Try the next example:
[JSFiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/5uamyea1/3/
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JQuery for that, CSS transition property would do this. Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uamyea1/6/)

```
    .fa-chevron-circle-down{
          transition: 1s ease-in-out;
     }
    .fa-chevron-circle-down:hover{
          transform: translate(0px,40px);
     }
```